# Ask for a hint of some proof about inverse function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question in the next proof, and I'd like to someone gives me a hint.

**Definition**: The function $f$ is invertible $\iff$  $f^{-1}$ is a functional relation.

**Proposition 1** : Let $f$ be a function. If there exists some function $g$ such that $g \circ f = 1_{domf}$ then $f$ is invertible and $f^{-1} = g\restriction ran f.$

Proof:

**Claim 1**: $f$ is invertible if and only if $f$ is injective.

Proof of claim 1:

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $f$ is invertible. For $f$ be an injection is necessary to show that $\,x_{1} f y\,$ and $\,x_{2} f y\,$ implies $x_{1} =x_{2}$. By definition of inverse relation, $\,x_{1} f y\,$ is equivalent to $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{1},\,$ symmetrically $\,x_{2} f y\,$ to $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{2}.\,$ So, we have $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{1}\,$ and $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{2}.\,$ Since $\,f^{-1}\,$ is functional, implies $x_{1} =x_{2}.\,$ Then $f$ is an injection as desired.

($\Leftarrow$) Now suppose $f$ is injective. We need to show that $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{1}\,$ and $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{2},\,$ implies $x_{1} =x_{2}.\,$ By definition of inverse relation $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{1}\,$ iff $\,x_{1} f y\,$ and $\,y\, f^{-1} x_{2},\,$ iff $\,x_{2} f y.\,$ So, if we assumed that $f$ is an injection, $\,x_{1} f y\,$ and $\,x_{2} f y\,$ implies $x_{1} =x_{2}\,$ as desired. We conclude that $f^{-1}$ is functional, i.e, $f$ is invertible. $\;\Box$

By claim 1, just we need to show that $f$ is an injection. Suppose $x_{1}, x_{2} \in dom f$ and  $x_{1} \not= x_{2}.\,$

If $\langle x_{1}, x_{1} \rangle \in 1_{domf} = g\circ f\, $ and $\langle x_{2}, x_{2} \rangle \in 1_{domf} = g\circ f.\, $ By definition of composition, there is some $y_{1}$ respectively $y_{2}$ such that $x_{1} f y_{1},\, x_{2} f y_{2}$ and $y_{1}\,g\, x_{1},\, y_{2}\,g\, x_{2}$. By hypothesis we assumed that $x_{1} \not= x_{2}$ then $y_{1} \not= y_{2}$ if were not, $g$ cannot be a function. So, $f$ is an injection as desired.

To conclude the proof only rest to show that $f^{-1} = g\restriction ran f.$

But here is where I'm stuck. Does someone have a hint, please?

As usual thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$. Then $g(y)=x$, so $\langle y,x\rangle\in g$. Moreover, $y\in\operatorname{ran}f$, so $\langle y,x\rangle\in g\upharpoonright\operatorname{ran}f$. And $f^{-1}=\{\langle y,x\rangle:\langle x,y\rangle\in f\}$, so ... ?

Comment: So, $\langle y,x \rangle \in f^{-1},\,$ implies $\langle y,x \rangle \in g\restriction ran f,$  which means $ f^{-1} \subseteq g\restriction ran f.\, $  For the converse, now suppose that $\langle y,x \rangle \in g\restriction ran f,\,$ so $y \in ran f$ and by definition of $ran f$, there exists some $x^{*}$ such that $\langle x^{*},y\rangle\in f.$ And as, $\langle x^{*},y\rangle\in f $ and $\langle y,x \rangle \in g\restriction ran f,\,$  implies $\langle x^{*},x \rangle \in 1_{domf}$ then $x^{*}= x.\,$

Comment: Then $\langle x,y\rangle\in f,\,$ by definition of inverse relation $\langle y,x \rangle \in f^{-1},$ which means $g\restriction ran f \subseteq f^{-1}.\, $ Hence, $g\restriction ran f = f^{-1}.\, $ Is this correct? If so, I knew it, it was too easy. Thanks as usual.

Comment: @Jose: Looks good. You're welcome.